# EF Linq can't convert sql query to the right linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following sql query and I can't translate it to the right linq statement.

```sql
SELECT 
    r.RoleName,
    uir.UserId
FROM 
    webpages_Roles r
         LEFT JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles uir ON uir.RoleId = r.RoleId 
                                                  AND r.AppId = 1
WHERE
     uir.UserId IS NULL
```

In my c# I have something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Role> roles = uow.RolesRepository.Get(r => r.AppId == 1 && r.UsersInRoles.Any(uir => uir.UserId == null), includeProperties: "UsersInRoles");
```

I'm using a repository, but it could also be:

```
IEnumerable<Role> roles = context.Roles.Where(r => r.AppId == 1 && r.UsersInRoles.Any(uir => uir.UserId == null));
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx see how LEFT JOIN is built with LINQ

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Enumerable roles = context.Roles
    .Where(r => r.AppId == 1 && !r.UsersInRoles.Any(uir => uir.UserId != null));
```